# Rails works fine but not in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My rails app is working fine when I'm running it locally in Ubuntu, but once I deployed it to herokuapp, it causes an error.

```
forw = Forward.select(:user_id).where(:doc_id => params[:id])
@users = User.where.not(:id => "#{@user.id}").where.not(:id => forw)
@sent = User.where.not(:id => "#{@user.id}").where(:id => forw)
# line 41 is below ↓
@status = Forward.select(:status).where(user_id: @sent.ids).where(doc_id: params[:id])
```

I think this is where the error is? this is a query in one of my controllers. Any help will be appreciated.

This is the heroku log when I execute the herokuapp.

```
2018-07-12T10:06:51.973236+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-12T10:06:51.973159 #4]  INFO -- : [fb2eda7a-41f6-49a8-9383-29902a059f61] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974312+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-12T10:06:51.974236 #4] FATAL -- : [fb2eda7a-41f6-49a8-9383-29902a059f61]
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974419+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-12T10:06:51.974348 #4] FATAL -- : [fb2eda7a-41f6-49a8-9383-29902a059f61] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = text
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974422+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...sers" WHERE ("users"."id" != $1) AND "users"."id" IN (SELECT...
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974424+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974426+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974430+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" != $1) AND "users"."id" IN (SELECT "forwards"."user_id" FROM "forwards" WHERE "forwards"."doc_id" = $2)):
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974525+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-12T10:06:51.974459 #4] FATAL -- : [fb2eda7a-41f6-49a8-9383-29902a059f61]
2018-07-12T10:06:51.974631+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-12T10:06:51.974567 #4] FATAL -- : [fb2eda7a-41f6-49a8-9383-29902a059f61] app/controllers/events_controller.rb:41:in `forward'
```

My gemfile in declaring the database

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: can you please add error log in question ?

Comment: I added the heroku log

Comment: What database are you using in development? Not postgres, I'd guess? Use the same database everywhere, to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: Which line is the 41 ?

Comment: I added the line number, but line 41 is @status = Forward.select(:status).where(user_id: @sent.ids).where(doc_id: params[:id])

Comment: I am using sqlite as the database

Comment: Do not use sqlite for production. An easy choice for heroku is postgresql, very easy to setup, lots of guides and documentatio

Comment: So should I change my database from sqlite to postgresql?

Comment: @tougherjan Yes. definitely

Comment: @users = User.where.not(:id => "#{@user.id}").where.not(:id => forw)  making complicated

Comment: @Gautam Kathrotiya what should I put?

Comment: you can do something like `User.where.not(id: [@user.id, forw])`

Comment: You seem to be passing a string to your query.

`User.where.not(:id => "#{@user.id}")`

is the `id` field a string?